# intellij-idea under awesome wm

Tags: swing, intellij-idea, awesome-wm

When using Awesome WM, Intellij main menu is broken.
It's either immediately closing after opening. Holding the mouse button keeps the menu open, but I can't select anything.
Sometimes the menu opening works, but the mouse cursor position is off. The selected item is approxmately one line below my mouse cursor.

I tried the recommended wmname LG3D fix, but it doesn't work.

wmname mutter helps sometimes. If the menu is working, the mouse cursor position is correct.
After some time the menu bugs out still and immediatly closes after clicking.

I think it's weird that I got these problem, as awesome is supposed to be a re-parenting wm now. FWIW, in i3-wm I didn't notice this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a statement from awesome wm and a potential bugfix: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java

Comment: Thanks to the linked post I had great success for intellij 13.1.4, ubuntu 12.04 and awesome 3.4.11. For my installation it did not matter if I used java6 or java7 to run intellij. I simply had to install the suckless-tools and use

    'wmname LG3D'

After this intellij started as hoped for (before that intellij did start, but the editor/explorer structure was not shown).

Answer (score 1):

My development environment is debian wheezy + awesome 3.4 + IntelliJ.

After I ran `./idea.sh` and created a new project, IntelliJ showed me a blank page. No menu, no explorers.

I don't know what happened anyway, but I followed [THIS](http://tools.suckless.org/wmname) and it worked.

**SUMMARY**

```
git clone http://git.suckless.org/wmname
sudo apt-get install -y libx11-dev
cd wmname
sudo make clean install

# The next two commands must be run within the same session.
wmname LG3D
./idea.sh
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem with installing [JDK6](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jdk6/)
I'll leave the question for reference

Comment: Did you upgrade to JDK6 or downgrade to it ? With RubyMine and Oracle JDK 7, I am facing the same issues.